# $\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}\frac{u^{-z}}{z(z+1)(z+2)...(z+m)}\ dz$

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}\frac{u^{-z}}{z(z+1)(z+2)...(z+m)}\ dz$$

This is how i tried it

$$\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty} \frac{u^{-z}}{z(z+1)(z+2)\cdots (z+m)}\,\mathrm dz \tag*{}$$

I will assume that $m\in \textbf{Z}^+$

Denote $I(t)$ as

$$ I(t) = \displaystyle \int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty} \frac{e^{tz}}{z(z+1)(z+2)\cdots (z+m)}\,\mathrm dz \tag*{}$$

Let $\mathcal L^{-1}\{F\}(s)=f(s)$ denote the inverse Laplace transform of $F(s)$

We have

$$\mathcal L^{-1}\{F\}(t)=f(t)=\frac1{2\pi i} \int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty} e^{zt}F(z)\,\mathrm dz \tag*{}$$

I dont have a good understanding of Laplace transform, so how should i proceed

Comment: Use the (repeated) convolution theorem for Laplace transforms.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}{\frac{u^{-z}}{z\left( z+1 \right) ...\left( z+m \right)}dz}
\\
=\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}{\frac{\Gamma \left( z \right)}{\Gamma \left( z+m+1 \right)}u^{-z}dz}
\\
\eta \left( x \right) =\begin{cases}
 0,x<0\\
 1,x\geqslant 0\\
\end{cases}
\\
\mathscr{M} \left[ \left( 1-u \right) ^m\eta \left( 1-u \right) \right] =\int_0^{\infty}{u^{z-1}\left( 1-u \right) ^m\eta \left( 1-u \right) du}
\\
=\int_0^1{u^{z-1}\left( 1-u \right) ^mdx}
\\
=\mathrm{B}\left( z,m+1 \right) =\frac{\Gamma \left( z \right) \Gamma \left( m+1 \right)}{\Gamma \left( z+m+1 \right)}
\\
\mathscr{M} ^{-1}\left[ \frac{\Gamma \left( z \right) \Gamma \left( m+1 \right)}{\Gamma \left( z+m+1 \right)} \right] =\frac{\Gamma \left( m+1 \right)}{2\pi i}\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}{\frac{\Gamma \left( z \right)}{\Gamma \left( z+m+1 \right)}u^{-z}dz}=\left( 1-u \right) ^m\eta \left( 1-u \right) 
\\
\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}{\frac{u^{-z}}{z\left( z+1 \right) ...\left( z+m \right)}dz}=\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}{\frac{\Gamma \left( z \right)}{\Gamma \left( z+m+1 \right)}u^{-z}dz}=\frac{2\pi i\left( 1-u \right) ^m\eta \left( 1-u \right)}{\Gamma \left( m+1 \right)}
$$

Answer (score 0):

First, if we assume that $u>0$, then $u^{-z} = e^{-z\log(u)}$. Now, rename $s=z$. Thus, your integral is:
$$
\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}\frac{e^{-s\log(u)}}{s(s+1)(s+2)...(s+m)}\ ds
$$
Now, consider the following integral, similarly as what you obtained:
$$
I(t) = \int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty} \frac{e^{st}}{s(s+1)(s+2)...(s+m)} ds
$$
where by evaluating $t=-\log(u)$, you recover the original integral.
Now, if $c<-m$ the integral doesn't converge. However, if $c>-m$ this is precisely the definition of the inverse Laplace transform (except for the $2\pi i$ factor):
$$
I(t) = 2\pi i\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left\{ \frac{1}{s(s+1)(s+2)...(s+m)}  \right\}
$$
So far, this is essentially what you already had. Now, to compute the transform there are two (equivalent) ways:

- Use partial fractions to expand
  $$
  \frac{1}{s(s+1)(s+2)...(s+m)}  = \frac{a_0}{s} + \frac{a_1}{s+1} + \cdots + \frac{a_m}{s+m}
  $$
  Then, using a table of transforms, recall that $\frac{a_n}{s+n}$ is the  Laplace transform of $a_ne^{-nt}$. Thus, $I(t) = 2\pi i\sum_{n=0}^m a_n e^{-nt}$
- Compute the integral using the residue theorem:
  $$
  \int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty} \frac{e^{st}}{s(s+1)(s+2)...(s+m)} ds = 2\pi i\sum_{n=0}^m \text{Res}\left\{\frac{e^{st}}{s(s+1)(s+2)...(s+m)}; -n\right\}
  $$
  where the residue of a function $f(s)$ at a (simple) pole $p$ is defined as
  $$
  \text{Res}\{f(s);p\} = \lim_{s\to p}(s-p)f(s)
  $$

Any of these two paths should give the correct result. Actually, even though they are conceptually different, you end up evaluating the same operations in each case.

Comment: The integral over $\operatorname {Re} s = c < -m$ converges (consider how the numerator and the denominator behave on a vertical line). If $c > -m$, the integral diverges if the contour goes through a pole of the integrand. When applying the residue theorem, you're assuming that you can take $[c - i R, c + i R] \cup \gamma_R$ s.t. all the poles are inside this new contour and $\lim_{R \to \infty} \int_{\gamma_R} = 0$. This can be done only for some $c$ and some $u > 0$.